# Flutter - Firebase Realtime Database remove listener for onChildAdded event

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to remove a listener for OnChildAdded.

```
var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('/users/$uid/donhang/cholayhang');

    var ls = ref.onChildAdded.listen((event) {
      count++;
      print(count);
    }).onError((e) {});
```

I tried a few ways follow Firebase official documents (off method), and search on google, but still not working.

```
    ref.off(); // not working
    ls.cancel(); // not working
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: "not working" is really hard to help with. Is there any error message?